# IPC_CREAT - Should it simply be seen as an "empty file" in the "memory"?

Tags: c

This is how a shared memory segment is created:

```
memory_id = shmget(key, memory_size, IPC_CREAT | 0755);
```

the 0755 portion tells me perhaps this is like creating a "file" on a file system that exists in the memory only.

is it correct to look at it in such way ?

does this also mean.. i must store data to it as if it is simply a file ?

in other words there can not be such thing as.. creating 2 files inside a file.

i must simply concatenate my strings, seperate them with a special character such as a pipe symbol. and write them all at once to the file that has been created in the memory ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, except for something... you cannot `write(2)` to a shared memory segment.  You have to `shmat(2)` to attach it to your process memory and then you can access it (as if it were a result from `malloc(2)` ---but it isn't, **you cannot `free(3)` it anyway**)

When you are finished, you can simply `shmdt(2)` as if you were freeing it (this doesn't free it as a system resource although, it continues to conserve its contents for another process to use them)

The `0755` is, indeed, the permission bits, as this resource is managed as a file.  When you `shmat(2)` it, permission bits are checked for access and you will get an error in case you don't have enough access to the resource.  Execute bits are not used, so your permissions should use `0644` instead (execute bits are reserved, so they should be `0`)

Shared memory segments are an expensive resource, as they consume system main memory (despite of them being *swapped out*, in case of need) and they don't disappear when the process that created them `exit(2)`s, so be careful, and they are available only until the system is rebooted.

Beware though that if you create references to places in the shared memory segment, they refer to private, virtual memory addresses in the virtual space of the writing process... if the memory segment is attached to the memory of another process, all those memory addresses will be invalid (or must be offseted to match the other process virtual memory space)